# Angular2 DataStore - authGuards no longer not working when using rxjs Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am building a User Profile Data Store so my Angular 2 app doesn't need to go to the server so frequently.  The app currently functions fine when I consume the service directly but when I add my data store layer in between it behaves as though my observable only emits one time (when my navigation bar component reads their currentuser.name). Components that consume the service seem to work, and my AuthGuards no longer work (which use the UserProfileStore to get the users info).  I suspect I am using Subject incorrectly and/or need to use some variant of *BehaviourSubject* or *ReplaySubject*, but I really don't know where to start.  My code is semi-based off of this example: [Cory Ryan Angular 2 Observable Data Services](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services)

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

**user-profile.store.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileStore implements OnDestroy {
private _currentUser:SjfrUser;
private _currentUser$: Subject<MyAppUser>;
private _subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this._currentUser$ = <Subject<MyAppUser>> new Subject();
}

getCurrentUser = () : Observable<MyAppUser> => {

    if (!this._currentUser) {
        let currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser(); // Performs http
        this._subscription = currentUser$.subscribe((currentUser: MyAppUser) => {                
            this._currentUser = currentUser;
            this._currentUser$.next(this._currentUser);
        });
    }

    return this._currentUser$.asObservable();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

}

**Auth-Guard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
    constructor(private userProfileStore: UserProfileStore, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {        

        let url: string = state.url;

        //var currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser(); // Works with this
        var currentUser$ = this.userProfileStore.getCurrentUser(); // No longer works            

        return currentUser$.map(x => {
            console.log("AuthGuard" + x.userName);  // This code no longer gets executed when using the datastore
            if (x.isExternalUser && url === '/external') {
                return true;
            } else if (x.isInternalUser && url === '/internal') {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
                return false;
            }
        });     


    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with .first() after map

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
    constructor(private userProfileStore: UserProfileStore, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {        

        let url: string = state.url;

        //var currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser(); // Works with this
        var currentUser$ = this.userProfileStore.getCurrentUser(); // No longer works            

        return currentUser$.map(x => {
            console.log("AuthGuard" + x.userName);  // This code no longer gets executed when using the datastore
            if (x.isExternalUser && url === '/external') {
                return true;
            } else if (x.isInternalUser && url === '/internal') {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/pagenotfound']);
                return false;
            }
        }).first();     


    }
```

Comment: That did not work. I am also trying to create a bit of a facade so that consumers (observers) don't have to change how they use the data store. I'd just like it to behave like a regular observable without pounding the server.